# map in c++ causes error

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have header file. I want a map object added to one of the structures. So I included

```
#include<map>
```

and compiled the program (note I did not use map object I just included it) and I got the following error

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:115:28: error: macro "value_compare" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:733:45: error: macro "value_compare" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/map:62:0,
                 from ../optimizer_types.h:16,
                 from ../main.cpp:20:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:115:28: error: macro "value_compare" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:656:45: error: macro "value_compare" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/map:61:0,
                 from ../optimizer_types.h:16,
                 from ../main.cpp:20:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:113:11: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare::comp'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:116:4: error: from this location
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:116:9: error: '__c' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:116:12: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:116:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:116:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h: In member function 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_comp() const':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:733:46: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/map:62:0,
                 from ../optimizer_types.h:16,
                 from ../main.cpp:20:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:113:11: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare::comp'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:4: error: from this location
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:9: error: '__c' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:12: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h: In member function 'std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_comp() const':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h:656:46: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

As an experiment I moved the include to a cpp file and it was compiling properly.

What could be the reason

Comment: "macro "value_compare" requires " looks like you have a macro called value_compare which interferes with the library internals

Comment: Do you try to use clang with gcc STL?

Comment: @PlasmaHH That function is in this file /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h

Comment: @MateuszPusz No just gcc

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's almost certainly the case.  Some file included earlier has defined this macro---practically speaking, this means that that file cannot be included in a C++ program.

Comment: @MateuszPusz The command is g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lpolylib64 -lpthread -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"

Comment: What extension has your file ? You say, you moved the include into cpp file, but where are you now ? Anyway you have to have a C++ extension, otherwise the compiler tries to compile as C-file and this should produce errors.

Comment: @JamesKanze But is is working properly when I include the same in a cpp file which includes even this header file

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am including another lib which probably have that macro. How can I over come this situation

Comment: @Debian Did you try to put `#include <map>` as the first line in your header file and that file as a first line in your cpp file? If it works or changes the error message it means that other headers you use redefine that macro in other place.

Comment: @MateuszPusz Yes I have tried now. I was thinking along the same lines. But strangely it shows the same error

Comment: @Debian: rename the macro or dont use that library.

Comment: You can use `g++ -E` to pre-process your file (use that instead of `-c`) and then inspect the output for where the macro `value_compare` is defined.

Comment: @MarkB That reduced the error to but still /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:115:28: error: macro "value_compare" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Comment: please note that there is error on /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h and  /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_multimap.h

Comment: @PlasmaHH I cannot rename the macro in both the libraries..... but I have to use both

Comment: @Debian: the macro is not in both libraries, only ni one, and if you can not rename it, you can not use all these things together, simple as that.

Comment: @Debian If a library header defines a macro with that name, you _cannot_ use it in C++, until you've modified the library to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#ifdef value_compare
#undefine value_compare // std::map header doesn't like this
#endif
#include <map>
```

It's not very flexible (or pretty) but it should get you through this :(

Edit: Either way, the problem is not including map, but the earlier include/code that defined value_compare macro. Is it a C header? (I doubt a C++ would define a macro with this name, as value_compare is an important part of the C++ standard library).